# Moving a Joomla Version 1.5.18 website to a new host

Tags: joomla1.5

I have to move a Joomla website that is of version 1.5.18, but I just cannot get it right.

If I install the newest version of Joomla on a new host it has different folder and database structures that do not match the ones of v1.5.18.

Comment: Also I can suggest you to use http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658 but I was unable to succeed

Answer (score 2):

Just get a copy of Akeeba backup. The backup file it creates will have everything you need to move the site to a new host. It's free and easy, shouldn't take more than 30 minutes with 25 minutes of that being uploading and downloading the file.

That said - you are probably better off either upgrading the site or building a new one from scratch. You are horribly out of date. Not only is your 1.5.x 8 versions behind, but the 1.5 series stopped being supported over a year ago. Your site will be hacked sooner or later and you will most certainly have your account suspended by your host. Then you will be forced to upgrade AND your site will be down. Better to do it now while the site is still up than have to rush through it later.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to install brand new Joomla! Instead, migrate the current site to new host

- Export your current db from your server using phpmyadmin
- Back up your files
- Switch to new host
- Import your db into new server using
  phpmyadmin again
- restore the files to the new server using an FTP
  client software such as WinSCP
- It is done

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to update connection to db and root folder in configuration.php after transferring